# Extension 'ms-vscode.remote-explorer' CANNOT use API proposal: localization

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I'm trying to open an API that I installed on a server. But when I try to connect to it I get this error message:

[image: Error message]

I have created a public and private key and set up the .ssh config file like this:

```
Host ysjcs.net
    HostName ysjcs.net
    User y.lu1
    IdentityFile ~/id_VSCode
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

I already tried adding "extensionsAny" to "ms-vscode.remote-explorer", but it was there.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: does this work for you? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7194#issuecomment-1249150914 if so, I can write up an answer post. please also add version info for your remote SSH extension. is it v0.102? if the think I linked to doesn't work for you, then try going through [the official troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/wiki/Remote-SSH-troubleshooting) and tell us what you find.